A difficulty in Parshat Behaalosecha chap. 11
Rashi on Numbers 11:10 writes:

בכה למשפחתיו: משפחות משפחות נאספים ובוכים לפרסם תרעמתן בגלוי. ורבותינו
אמרו (יומא ע"ה) למשפחתיו, על עסקי משפחות —על עריות הנאסרות להם
weeping with their families: Families gathered in groups weeping so as
to publicize their grievance. Our Sages say that the meaning is:
“concerning family matters,” that is, because intermarriage among
family members was forbidden to them.

If as Rashi says, what those people truly craved was forbidden sexual relations, how would stuffing them with quail meat satisfy them?
Better to let them have a big orgy like at the golden calf, then slaughter them en masse as Korach and his followers were!

Yerios Shlomo says illicit relations would mostly take place at an outhouse, and they were annoyed at being deprived of their pretense by the manna which produced no bodily waste.

A lot of the non-Halachic exegisis in the Talmud is on the level of דרוש or רמז, in order to teach us a general lesson rather than a historical one.

Gur Aryeh on this spot explains that this comment is to be understood as follows: the complaint about food was had an underlying component as well: too much focus on physical desires, which arayot often embodies. Thus, it is not saying the did not complain about food, but that the complaint also had an additional dimension. Further, Yoma 75a, the source of this idea, backs up the fact that this was meant as an additional layer of meaning and not to replace the primary meaning of wanting food.
Yeriot Shlomo suggests two answers:

That perhaps the connection is that the manna had a property that it diminished sexual desire, and that is why the complaint for food had this underlying latent meaning.

Arayot were more likely to occur in the field, where people would go to use the bathroom. Since the manna was absorbed by the body, people lost their excuse to go to the field alone.


Further, if we look in Bamidbar Rabbah and Tanchuma, the idea is fleshed out further. The motivation behind this interpretation is that it seems ludicrous to request food when they had animals, and the Manna was reportedly delicious. Thus, the opinion makes a play on words: basar, flesh, can also mean flesh of erva. This additional information suggests another possibility: since their illicit desire was about basar, they were thus punished with basar, albeit of a different form.
